# Initialize infopath in the code

Tags: sharepoint-2007, infopath, infopath-2007

I'm developping a workflow on MOSS 2007 and i'm trying to initialize my infopath in the code. Is it possible ?

Cheers,

Skilpit

Answer (score 2):

yes this is possible kindly have a look from following code 
[MSDN Code](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/HeadcountReqWorkflow/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2309)